# Fade an Image Using JavaScript (NOT JQuery!)

Tags: javascript, html, image

Hey everyone I have a homework question,

I need to fade in and out an image "gallery-style" using JavaScript. Note: NOT JQuery. I cannot use JQuery, per the assignment outline.

So there's a grid of images (32 of em if you care) they're all 100x100px thumbnails. Each one is in its own div, and the whole thing is nested inside another div, like so:

***gallery.html***

```
<div id="imageContent">

<div id="img" class="imageWhite" 
     onclick="fade(1984)"
     onmouseover="highlightWhiteFunction(this)" 
     onmouseout="unHighlightFunction(this)"> 
     <img src="../Media/Thumbs/1984.jpg"/> 
</div>

...31 others just like that

</div> //End of the whole container
```

So when you click on one of these images, it should fade that image in over the top of everything else. The width of this picture should be 500px, but the height can vary so distortion doesn't occur. Again, I CANNOT use JQuery for this...and yes, I know that'd make life a lot easier.

So far I only have a debug thing to detect that I can at least find which one is clicked on:

***gallery.js***

```
function fade(name) {
    var theName = name;
    console.debug("Clicked " + theName);
}
```

If the user clicks anywhere on this image, it needs to fade out. If the user clicks another thumbnail, it doesn't need to fade out, it can just disappear, but the other one needs to start fading in.

My thoughts:
Obviously I need a hidden div with width 500, and when these actions occur, I hide/unhide the div as necessary. The gist I've gotten from the professor is that to use JavaScript, you change the opacity in relation to a passage of time that you get from the system.

What I'm looking for in an answer here is maybe some clearer (more detailed) hints on how to go about this. I know how it needs to look, and I'm pretty sure I know the high-level of how to do it, I just don't know how to start doing it with code.

Any help would be appreciated, and I'll be around to answer any follow-up questions.

Again: NO JQuery! :)

Comment: You may accomplish this using CSS3 Animations.. The JS will only toggle the css effect class.

Comment: JSYK, that's not how you do comments in HTML

Comment: and also, how you do those event handlers is old and obstrusive. Use JS to loop through and apply handlers

Comment: @Markasoftware Yeah I know that's not an HTML comment, but I figured it'd suffice for this question. I agree that the handlers are major bummers, but we haven't gotten to any other solutions in class yet.

Comment: @enapupe  Thanks for the advice, I'm looking into this now. I'm surprised we didn't talk about that in class...seems like a really nice solution.

Comment: You will have to use some kind of CSS, at least the opacity. The `setTimeout` JS function will allow you to execute a function on a delay, like 50 milliseconds or something. Then, from within the function, call the `setTimeout` again on the same function until you reach some end condition where you don't re-call the function, and the animation is over.

Comment: ...that is if you have to use JS in the solution.

Comment: It's kind've weird that your teacher expects you to do some cool transition stuff but they don't even tell you a better way to attach listeners?

Comment: If you go with a JS Loop, check "request animation frame" (rAF).

Comment: @jwatts1980 No, I don't have to use JS, I should have been more precise with that. We get HTML (duh) and CSS3 (yep) and we can use JavaScript, and a few other requirements that I've already nailed required JS. So I mean, if this can be accomplished without JS, I don't care, I just have 3 different tools to use :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
 function fadeIn(el, time) {
     el.style.opacity = 0;
     el.style.display = "block";

     var last = +new Date();
     var tick = function() {
          el.style.opacity = +el.style.opacity + (new Date() - last) / time;
          last = +new Date();

          if (+el.style.opacity < 1) {
               (window.requestAnimationFrame && requestAnimationFrame(tick)) ||      setTimeout(tick, 16)
          }
     };

     tick();
}
```

Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cEDbs/

Just bind the image onclick to call that method with the element.

Comment: God bless you. This is fantastic, I really appreciate this. Really fantastic solution, I'll be able to adapt this well to my needs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, your solution uses document.getELement..... and it seems to require that the image already be somewhere on the page. So, is there some way I can pass a new image source to it? Like somehow do fadeIn(img src="../Media/Large/1984.jpg", 1000)?

Comment: If you can use `requestAnimationFrame` then you likely have access to `Date.now()` for ms since the epoch. This should be preferred over in both cases above.

Comment: @Joodoo You could append the element to the div with display: none and then call the fadeIn function on it.

Comment: @RyanPrintup So, I've got 32 images total in a gallery. 4 rows of 8 image thumbnails. Does that mean I need 32 of these hidden divs? Or can I append 32 images into the div? (Essentially: click on 1 of these 32 images, fade in THAT image into the hidden div)

Comment: @Joodoo Are the images already loaded on your website before hand in a gallery fashion or are you adding them after an action occurs? If you are adding them later you are still adding them somewhere on your website where you can just call fadeIn() afterwards.

Comment: @RyanPrintup Right, I'm adding them AFTER they're clicked on. The idea here is bandwidth management in addition to these little animations. So, the first thumbnail is called 1984.jpg and it's in the Thumbs folder. If I click on that, I want to load 1984.jpg from the Large folder. If I never click it, it never loads. So, where would you recommend I load that Large image?

Comment: @Joodoo Since it is a thumbnail are you going to a page that has just that image or do you want a popup of some sort? Or are you just replacing the thumbnail?

Comment: @RyanPrintup Good clarification, my apologies for not making it sooner. This first link is what my page looks like right now: http://imgur.com/uHJ0GU8     And this second link is the example that our professor gave us (plus artistic license to make the page our own) that includes a "before and after" of the gallery, and then the image faded in: http://imgur.com/CMxvovY

Comment: @RyanPrintup And I just realized I still didn't answer your question directly: I'm doing neither, the thumbnail stays on the page, and it's not a pop-up window.

Comment: @Joodoo That makes more sense now. I recommend creating a div that has "position: absolute" with an id of "image-popup" or something in your HTML, probably at the end. Style this box and add a close button that will just fade out the div (Reverse the fadeIn method for fadeOut). Then whenever an image is clicked you can grab the full-sized image and add it to an image container div inside the popup div. Afterwards, call fadeIn on the actual popup div. That should work, however for figuring out what full-size image goes with what thumbnail can be a little more tricky. --Continued

Comment: @Joodoo You could do something like add a custom data- attribute that contains a link to the full-size image and grab it with javascript on click. Another way it to have both images have the same name but in different directories like '/thumbnails/' and '/images/' then grab the thumbnail's name and link to the same image but in the '/image/' directory. Hopefully that helped you out.

Comment: @Joodoo Don't need position: absolute if it isn't a popup then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a CSS based solution.  The fade may not be exactly like you want, but can easily be adjusted.  Try out the JSFiddle and click an image to see a css transition-- clicking an image fades it larger. Click again fades it back.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rh976/

```
<img src="http://tippvet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/cat-vet.jpg" class="img img1"/>
<img src="http://tippvet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/cat-vet.jpg" class="img img2"/>
<img src="http://tippvet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/cat-vet.jpg" class="img img3"/>
<img src="http://tippvet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/cat-vet.jpg" class="img img4"/>
```

**JS**

```
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    var img = imgs[i];
    img.addEventListener('click',function(e){  
        if(!this.className.match(/big/)){          
            this.className += ' big'; 
        } else {
             this.className = this.className.replace(/big/,'');
        }
    });        
}
```

**CSS**

```
.img {
    -webkit-transition: all 1.0s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1.0s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 1.0s ease-out;

    position:absolute;   
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
    z-index:1;
}

.img.img1 { top: 10px;  left: 10px; }
.img.img2 { top: 10px;  left:170px; } 
.img.img3 { top:120px;  left: 10px; }
.img.img4 { top:120px;  left:170px; } 

.img.big {
    position:absolute;
    width:450px;  
    height:300px;
    top:10px;
    left:10px;
    z-index:20;
}
```